# React Router v4 replace history when component is unmounted

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a app which has the Following Components

> |__Base   -  /home/Base
>
> |__Try   - /home/Base/:try
>
> |__Report   - /home/Base/:try/report

Base is the Starting screen where the user hits a button and clicks on Try and after trying some things he hits submits which generates reports which has some back end interactions and when the data is fetched it loads the Reports.

So what i want is when the user hits the back button from the Reports Page he should not land on the Try page but on the Base page .

For that to work i went through the react router documentation and was trying to use `history.replace` on `componentWillUnmount` for Reports Page

```
this.props.history.replace(`/home/Base`, {
  pathname: `/home/Base`,
  search: null,
  state: {
    isActive: true
  }
}, null);
```

In case the Report Page is FullyLoaded and i press the back button it works but calls the Try Render Method too and then takes me to the Base Page , But in case of Reports Not fully Loaded and i press the back button while the loading spinner is in progress it goes to base page still but also mounts and unmounts the TRY component.

> What am i missing here , what causes it to mount/unmount or render the previous component and then load the base component even though i replace the history stack ?

Comment: Out of question but what about use link button directly route to prev page?

Comment: @keikai what if the user presses the browser back button

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, still out of question but, maybe we can set `componentWillMount` in `Try` to check whether the previous page is `Report`, if so route to `Base`, is it a good approach?

Comment: I am not getting the solve actually can you ellborate

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason

Related with this [issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5325)

> React v16, changing routes, componentWillMount of the new route is called before componentWillUnmount of the old route

Update:

#### Solution (checked, update online demo later)

Use [react-router-last-location](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-last-location) to get previous pathname

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LastLocationProvider } from 'react-router-last-location';

<BrowserRouter>
  <LastLocationProvider>
    <Switch>
     ...
    </Switch>
  </LastLocationProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Check previous pathname in `componentWillMount`, if it's from certain page, push a new pathname to route.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    const { history, lastLocation } = this.props;
    if (lastLocation?.pathname === '/home/Base/:try/report') {
      history.push({pathname: '/home/Base'});
    }
  }
```

You can use the HOC they provide or write it yourself refer to the lib's source to reduce the dependencies

```
import { withLastLocation } from 'react-router-last-location';

interface Props {
  lastLocation: any,
  history: any,
}

export const YourComponent = withLastLocation(connect(
  ...
))
```

In this way you can redirect all the routing process from certain pages without mount current page, no matter you clicked a `back` button or clicked the back in your browser.

Comment: how will you acquire `if (lastLocation.pathname` can you please shed some light there

Comment: As I mentioned above, there are also libs like [react-router-last-location](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-last-location), feel free check it.

Comment: where as i do agree with the solve but just to get the last solve i need to import a lib of 51.kb i sonot see that as a solve .. this works but not for a prod ready code , what if i donot have any utiltites and how do we get past this.. this kind of looks like a workaround rather a potential solve using react router

Comment: You are right about what you say, as well as still you can watch the source of that libs like [here](https://github.com/hinok/react-router-last-location/blob/master/src/withLastLocation.tsx) then do it yourself in your own project, and that's what I really mean, I mean this lib provide the solution around it which you can refer.

Comment: And the answer above seems have already answered your question well enough. Inspire me if you need any further assistance.

Comment: i will check on it and let you know , will accept it post that, just upvoting for now as i feel the solution is not exact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207238/discussion-between-keikai-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: i have added thing in the chat please check