# Going back to previous page when close app using returnValue in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onbeforeunload

I have a scenario where I need to prevent window close and go back to previous page. So, I used 
**beforeunload** to prevent window close and redirect to previous page. But the problem is when the page redirect to its previous window it doesn’t able to load pictures. Is there any reason for that? how can i fix this problem?

```
function goBackPrev(e) {
      e.returnValue = '';
      store.dispatch(actions.redirect(login/user));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', goBackPrev);
      });
```

Comment: Any code of `login/user`'s  picture rendering?

Comment: @keikai not only login/user page, it actually shows same whenever I try to redirect any page.

Comment: You can use life-cycle to handle it I guess. Refer to this related [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60053624/react-router-v4-replace-history-when-component-is-unmounted/60054687#60054687)