# How to clear history after successful login in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on react web app.I integrated azure authentication in my webpage, After successful login it is navigating to home page. But if i click browser back button it is again showing azure authentication page. How to stop going to login page.

```
code:

   this.props.history.replace("/home")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60054687/11872246

Comment: No, i just need to clear all microsoft login pages

Comment: If you need to override the browser `back` button's action, I think that fits your demand. There are plenty of solutions for programmatical back to another page, but not so much for the browser one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear browsing history using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-javascript)